# How to connect to remote hostinger mysql server in node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron, remote-server

Am making a electron desktop app for fetching exam results which will be 
  displayed as a table(am stating  this because i don't want to use 'grant 
  permission' query in sql means this app will be used by many students not 
  just me)

i tried below code 
  am getting ENOTFOUND getaddrinfo mysql.hostinger.in error.

can it be solved by any npm package?if not please provide the code.Thanks

```
//code

var mysql = require('mysql');

note:fake parameters were given

var conn= mysql.createConnection({

host: "remote_host",

user: "MJ",

password: "This*is*it",

database: "POP"
});

conn.connect((err)=>{

if(err)
  return console.log(err.stack);

 console.log("remote connection successfull");

});
```

Comment: Is remote connection enabled on your SQL Server ?

Comment: good question..now how to enable remote connection in my remote sql server am using hostinger!..

Comment: Well they probably allow you to configure this via the cPanel https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/cpanel/how-to-use-remote-mysql-feature.

But you have to be aware that the connection may not be encrypted. I am not sure how far you're allowed to run stuff on your hosting package but another option would be to write a API that handles the SQL connection on the Server but lets you interface with it via https

Comment: yea i jus saw that ....but to enable that feauture i have to  upgrade my account it seems...is there no free solution for this?

Comment: Well you could map your database to a API for example REST.

You would install a REST Service (either in nodejs or php) on the server, and your electron app needs a rest client. They can then interact with each other. Good luck and happy coding ;)